# splitting string by whitespace and then joining it again in ansible/jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to "cleanup" whitespaces in a variable in Ansible (ansible-2.1.1.0-1.fc24.noarch) playbook and I though I'll first **split()** it and then **join(' ')** again. For some reason that approach is giving me error below :-/

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    mytext: |
      hello
      there how   are
      you?
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mytext }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mytext.split() }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mytext.split().join(' ') }}"
...
```

Gives me:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.122.193] => {
    "msg": "hello\nthere how   are\nyou?\n"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.122.193] => {
    "msg": [
        "hello", 
        "there", 
        "how", 
        "are", 
        "you?"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.122.193]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'join'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '.../tests.yaml': line 15, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n        msg: \"{{ mytext.split() }}\"\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? It says *the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'join'*, but according to [useful filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) docs, it should work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use pipe to apply a filter:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ mytext.split() | join(' ') }}"
```

In this example `split()` is a Python method of string object. So it's a bit hackery.
And `join(' ')` is a Jinja2 filter that concatenates a list into string.

By calling `mytext.split().join(' ')` you get error, because there is no `join` method for lists in Python.
There is `join` method for string in Python and you can call `' '.join(mytext.split())`, but it will be a double hack.

Comment: Damn, I was pretty sure I have tried that. Why is the `mytext.split() | join(' ')` deffierent from `mytext.split().join(' ')` anyway? Thank you!

Comment: Jinja filter `join` (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join) vs. non-existent method `join` for lists in python.
There is only `join` for `str` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).