# Ansible: Extract first three octects from an IP address

Tags: regex, ansible, jinja2

I have a string with IP addr: `192.168.10.2`

I want to extract first three octets of the IP in Ansible and I tried to use this regex.

```
{{comp_ip | regex_replace("^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}"), "//1"}}
```

This does not yield any result. Can someone correct me where I went wrong?

Comment: You want `192.168.10` to be returned?

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If already have dot-separated IP-address, there is a simple way:

```
{{ comp_ip.split('.')[0:3] | join('.') }}
```

Comment: this is a cool trick and clear. So in general can we use any python methods through pipe in ansible?

Comment: No, pipes are for filters, see my [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39794185/2795592) answer for details. But you can use python methods of strings and dicts with dot-notation.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right, you just have to use parenthesis in Regex to make a group. It is better to match the whole `ip` and end your regex with `$`, and also change `//1` to `\\1` in your code.

Change regex from:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}
```

To this regex:

```
^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\.[0-9]{1,3}$
```

This is the full code:

```
{{comp_ip | regex_replace('^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\.[0-9]{1,3}$', '\\1')}}
```

Comment: thanks, but it has some issue with syntax I bileve.
The offending line appears to be:

  set_fact:
    net: {{comp_ip | regex_replace('^([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})'), '\\1'}}
                                                         ^ here

Comment: No syntax error with this, but o/p has nothing in it
{"net": "(u'', '\\\\1')"}

Comment: @spamulap12 Try the updated full code, I made a small change. By the way, does the input has only `ip`? or does it have something before, and after the `ip`?

Comment: This is the full ansible code I am trying with
`code`
- name: COMP IP
  set_fact:
    comp_ip: "192.168.10.2"
 
- name: Extract net
  set_fact:
    net: "{{comp_ip | regex_replace('^[\s\S]*?([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})[\s\S]*$'), '\\1'}}"

I get the syntax error like before :(

Comment: The full code has a typo, the closing bracket of regex_replace should be after the \\1
`{{comp_ip | regex_replace('^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\.[0-9]{1,3}$', '\\1')}}`

Comment: @spamulap12 Yes, you're right, how did we miss that.

Comment: @spamulap12 my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to calculate your network address you can use Ansible **ipaddr filter** which provides exactly this functionality:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}/{{ ansible_default_ipv4.netmask }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="network {{ my_ip | ipaddr('network') }}"
    - debug: msg="netmask {{ my_ip | ipaddr('netmask') }}"
```